# Unable to set number format

Tags: c#, asp.net, number-formatting, spreadsheetgear

I want to put the number format for Peruvian Soles

Spreadsheetgear gave me this format: `"S/."#,##0_);("S/."#,##0)` - but I don't know how to cast that string to put in:

```
reportWorkbook.Worksheets[WSNombre].Cells[CPasoMOS].NumberFormat = "HERE";
```

I tried:

```
reportWorkbook.Worksheets[WSNombre].Cells[CPasoMOS].NumberFormat = "S/. ###,##0.00"; 
reportWorkbook.Worksheets[WSNombre].Cells[CPasoMOS].NumberFormat = "S/.#,##0_";
reportWorkbook.Worksheets[WSNombre].Cells[CPasoMOS].NumberFormat = "S/.#,##0";
```

BUT none of the above works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Excel needs the quotation marks in "S/. " to recognise this as text.

You need to escape the quotes in your string like this:

```
reportWorkbook.Worksheets[WSNombre].Cells[CPasoMOS].NumberFormat = "\"S/. \"#,##0";
```

See also [this guide to Excel formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-a-custom-number-format-HP010342372.aspx).